# Is it possible to compare #ifdef values for conditional use

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to come up with a generic, easy to use way to only run certain code, depending upon the api I am using at the time.

In a header:

```
#define __API_USED cocos2d-x

#define COCOS2DX  cocos2d-x
#define OPENGL opengl

#ifdef __API_USED == COCOS2DX
    #define USING_COCOS2DX
    #undef USING_OPENGL
#endif
```

in source:

```
#ifdef USING_COCOS2DX
    ......
#endif
```

However I don't think this would work.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Comment: Use `#if` instead of `#ifdef`.

Comment: `#define __API_USED cocos2d-x` - man, seeing that hyphen is weird.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: But that's only going to work if `__API_USED` and `COCOS2DX` expand to integer expressions. The preprocessor isn't going to recognize `cocos2d-x`; it will treat it as `0 - 0` unless `cocos2d` and `x` are macros.

Comment: Rather than defining `__API_USED` and then checking its value to define another macro, why not define `USING_COCOS2DX` or `USING_OPENGL` directly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can but you need to do it like this:

```
#define __API_USED COCOS2DX

#define COCOS2DX  1
#define OPENGL 2

#if __API_USED == COCOS2DX
    #define USING_COCOS2DX
    #undef USING_OPENGL
#endif
```

As Keith Thompson explained undefined tokens (macros) like `cocos2d` and `x` evaluate to `0` so you need to define values for the macros you're using.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand this correctly, `cocos2d-x` is one of several possible APIs.

The preprocessor can test whether a symbol is defined or not (using `#ifdef` and the `defined` operator), and it can evaluate constant integer expressions (using `#if`).

One approach would be to define a numeric code for each API:

```
#define COCOS2X         1
#define ANOTHER_API     2
#define YET_ANOTHER_API 3
/* ... */
```

and then:

```
#define API_USED COCOS2DX
#if API_USED == COCOS2DX
    #define USING_COCOS2DX
    #undef USING_OPENGL
#elif API_USED == ANOTHER_API
    /* ... */
#elif API_USED == YET_ANOTHER_API
    /* ... */
#endif
```

Note that I've changed your macro name `__API_USED` to `API_USED`. Identifiers starting with two underscores (or with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter) are reserved to the implementation for all purposes; you shouldn't define them in your own code.

One drawback of this approach is that misspellings won't be flagged; the preprocessor quietly replaces any undefined identifiers with the constant `0`.

It's probably better to have an identifier for each API, and define it if and only if that API is being used:

```
#define USING_COCOS2X
/* #undef USING_COCOS2X */
```

and then:

```
#if USING_API_COCOS2X
    #undef USING_OPENGL
#endif
```

Testing whether a macro is defined or not tends to be more robust than testing whether it has a specific value.

You then just have to make sure that the `USING_API_*` macros (if there are several) are defined consistently.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with clang 8.1.0 (from Xcode 8.3.2). Suppose, in a header file, we want to test `CONFIG` for the value `special`. In any given translation unit, `CONFIG` might be unset, or might be set to `special`, or might be set to something else.

```
#define CAT_HELPER(lhs, rhs) lhs##rhs
#define CAT(lhs, rhs) CAT_HELPER(lhs, rhs)

#define TEST_PREFIX_special 1

#if CAT(TEST_PREFIX_, CONFIG)
#pragma message("detected CONFIG == 'special'")
#else
#pragma message("CONFIG != 'special'")
#endif
```

The double indirection (`CAT()` calls `CAT_HELPER()`) is important.

This tactic relies on `#if` expanding an undefined macro as `0`.